# Regex extraction in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data format from which I'm trying to extract the id part,
`{"memberurn"=urn:li:member:10000012}`
This is my code,

```
CAST(regexp_extract(key.memberurn, 'urn:li:member:(\\d+)', 1) AS BIGINT) AS member_id
```

In the output member_id is NULL
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Oracle, SQL-Server, MySQL, etc.?

Comment: @Barmar I'm using spark sql, the data is stored in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

 spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('practice')\
.getOrCreate()

 sc= spark.sparkContext

 df= sc.parallelize([
 [""" {"memberurn"=urn:li:member:10000012}"""]]).toDF(["a"])

 df.show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------+
|a                                    |
+-------------------------------------+
| {"memberurn"=urn:li:member:10000012}|
+-------------------------------------+


df1= df.withColumn("id", F.regexp_extract(F.col('a'), 
'(urn:li:member:)(\d+)', 2))


df2= df1.withColumn("id",df1["id"].cast(LongType()))


df2.show()

+-------------------------------------+--------+
|a                                    |id      |
+-------------------------------------+--------+
| {"memberurn"=urn:li:member:10000012}|10000012|
+-------------------------------------+--------+

print(df2.printSchema())


root
  |-- a: string (nullable = true)
  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I'm not using pySpark, but spark scala, but let me try this out.

Comment: I updated the code to cast id column to LongType Numerical

Answer (score 0):

In scala-

### Using regex_extract

```
val df = spark.range(1).withColumn("memberurn", lit("urn:li:member:10000012"))
    df.withColumn("member_id",
      expr("""CAST(regexp_extract(memberurn, 'urn:li:member:(\\d+)', 1) AS BIGINT)"""))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      * |id |memberurn             |member_id|
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      * |0  |urn:li:member:10000012|10000012 |
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      */
```

### Using substring_index

```scala
    df.withColumn("member_id",
      substring_index($"memberurn", ":", -1).cast("bigint"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      * |id |memberurn             |member_id|
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      * |0  |urn:li:member:10000012|10000012 |
      * +---+----------------------+---------+
      */
```